# How to show the content and hide the content conditionally in react using hooks

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project that I have to show content and hide the content conditionally when I click the button. For example, I have four buttons, First Button is Frontend, Second Button is Middleware, Third Button is Database, and Fourth Button is Apps.

By Default when I landed on the Home Page Frontend Button should be Highlighted remaining button should be normal. At that time I have to show only Frontend-related frameworks or libraries.

Now when I click Middleware Button then the Middleware Button should be Highlighted At that time I have to show Middleware Frameworks like Node Express etc.

Now when I click Database Button then the Database Button should be Highlighted At that time I have to show Database like Mongo Db, Casandra.

Now when I click Apps Button then the App Button should be Highlighted At that time I have to show Apps like React native, Flutter.

Please help me to achieve this task

This is Home.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Home.css'


const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-3'>
                    <button className='btn btn-primary mt-3'>Frontend</button>
                </div>
                <div className='col-3'>
                    <button className='btn btn-danger mt-3'>Middleware</button>
                </div>
<div className='col-3'>
                    <button className='btn btn-secondary mt-3'>Database</button>
                </div>
<div className='col-3'>
                    <button className='btn btn-info mt-3'>Apps</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='row mt-3'>
                <div className='col-3'>
                    <h3>React</h3>
                </div>
                <div className='col-3'>
                    <h3>Angular</h3>
                </div>
                <div className='col-3'>
                    <h3>Vue</h3>
                </div>
                <div className='col-3'>
                    <h3>Ember</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: hey check my answer for a more dynamic and scale able approach to your situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Home = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('frontend')
  const frontends = ['React', 'Angular', 'Vue']
  const middlewares = ['Node', 'Express', 'Hapi']
  const databases = ['MongoDB', 'MySQL', 'Casandra']
  const apps = ['React Native', 'Flutter']

  let showingArr = []
  if (selected === 'frontend') {
    showingArr = frontends
  } else if (selected === 'middleware') {
    showingArr = middlewares
  } else if (selected === 'database') {
    showingArr = databases
  } else if (selected === 'apps') {
    showingArr = apps
  }

  return (
      <div className='container'>
          <div className='row'>
              <div className='col-3'>
                  <button
                      className='btn btn-primary mt-3'
                      onClick={() => setSelected('frontend')}
                  >Frontend</button>
              </div>
              <div className='col-3'>
                  <button
                      className='btn btn-danger mt-3'
                      onClick={() => setSelected('middleware')}
                  >Middleware</button>
              </div>
              <div className='col-3'>
                  <button
                      className='btn btn-secondary mt-3'
                      onClick={() => setSelected('database')}
                  >Database</button>
              </div>
              <div className='col-3'>
                  <button
                      className='btn btn-info mt-3'
                      onClick={() => setSelected('apps')}
                  >Apps</button>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div className='row mt-3'>
              {
                  showingArr.map(item => (
                      <div className='col-3'>
                          <h3>{item}</h3>
                      </div>
                  ))
              }
          </div>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hi @baymax I edited my question so please edit your answer according to my question, It will be helpful for me thanks a lot.

Comment: @Vamsi Done. Hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

return(
    {show ? <content to show when state is true /> : null}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a more scale able way of doing this . in the future if you want to add new topics of different types for example `Python`which can be of type `AI`  , you want have to add an other condition check you can just add your AI toggle button and set `onClick` as `toggleListType('AI')`

```
import React, { useState ,useEffect} from 'react';
import './Home.css'


const Home = () => {
    const [listOFtopics,setlistOFtopics]=useState([
         {type:'FRONTEND',title:'react'},
         {type:'FRONTEND',title:'angular'},
         {type:'MIDDLEWEAR',title:'node'},
         {type:'MIDDLEWEAR',title:'express'},
     ])
    const [listOFtopicsToDisplay,setlistOFtopicsToDisplay]=useState([])

     useEffect(()=>{
        //initializing listOFtopicsToDisplay to show FRONEND related topics 
        setlistOFtopicsToDisplay(listOFtopics.filter(t=> t.type =="FRONTEND"))
     },[])

     const toggleListType=(type)=>{
         setlistOFtopicsToDisplay(listOFtopics.filter(t=> t.type ==type))
     }

    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-6'>
                    <button onClick={e=>toggleListType('FRONTEND')} className='btn btn-primary mt-3'>Frontend</button>
                </div>
                <div className='col-6'>
                    <button onClick={e=>toggleListType('MIDDLEWEAR')} className='btn btn-danger mt-3'>Middleware</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='row mt-3'>
                {
                 listOFtopicsToDisplay.map(t=><div className='col-3'><h3>Vue</h3</div>)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```